# CXF WS-Addressing with Decoupled Endpoint but without Jetty

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous, cxf, ws-addressing

Is it possible to use WS-Addressing with Decoupled Endpoint but without using Jetty,
simply using the ServletDestination ?

I'm getting the following exception and my SOAP header contains anynomous replyTo address:

```
2014-05-26 17:20:35,733 ERROR [org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory] (server_Worker-1) Cannot find any registered HttpDestinationFactory from the Bus.
2014-05-26 17:20:35,733 WARN  [org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.MAPAggregator] (server_Worker-1) decoupled endpoint creation failed:
java.io.IOException: Cannot find any registered HttpDestinationFactory from the Bus.
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getDestination(HTTPTransportFactory.java:296)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.impl.MAPAggregatorImpl.getDestination(MAPAggregatorImpl.java:990)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.impl.MAPAggregatorImpl.setUpDecoupledDestination(MAPAggregatorImpl.java:961)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.impl.MAPAggregatorImpl.createDecoupledDestination(MAPAggregatorImpl.java:945)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.impl.MAPAggregatorImpl.getReplyTo(MAPAggregatorImpl.java:930)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.impl.MAPAggregatorImpl.addRoleSpecific(MAPAggregatorImpl.java:850)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.impl.MAPAggregatorImpl.aggregate(MAPAggregatorImpl.java:617)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.impl.MAPAggregatorImpl.mediate(MAPAggregatorImpl.java:448)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.impl.MAPAggregatorImpl.handleMessage(MAPAggregatorImpl.java:143)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
        at $Proxy1106.doServiceWS(Unknown Source)
        at fr.edu.rennes.cyclades.pilotage.async.WSJob.executeTask(WSJob.java:116)
        at fr.edu.ac_rennes.webfusion.quartz.job.BaseJob.executeInternal(BaseJob.java:101)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:113)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
```

Payload:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Header>
                <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://api.service.support.cyclades.rennes.edu.fr/QuartzWebService/doServiceWS</Action>
                <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:34978730-9686-40ec-8e66-dcc68c0be27c</MessageID>
                <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://sapdcy1.in.ac-rennes.fr:8280/ws_centre/cxf/DeclarerCentresBatchService</To>
                <ReplyTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                        <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
                </ReplyTo>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body/>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Does anyone have a clue ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.
I set the decoupled_endpoint to an relative URL (not starting with http://... ) so CXF decide to use the ServletDestinationFactory instead of the JettyDestinationFactory (look at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getDestination(EndpointInfo)). 
Then I setup an CXF Interceptor that construct an absolute URL so the replyTo address in the SOAP Header contains a valid and callable HTTP address.

```
public class ReplyToInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

/** Le logger */
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReplyToInterceptor.class);

/** Host name */
private String hostName;
/** Host port */
private String hostPort;

/**
 * Constructeur par défaut
 */
public ReplyToInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.PRE_LOGICAL);
    addAfter(MAPAggregator.class.getName());
}

/**
 * Ajoute l'adresse de retour asynchrone
 * @param message Le message
 */
public void handleMessage(Message message) {
    if (message instanceof XMLMessage) {
        LOGGER.debug("Ignoring REST message");
        return;
    }
    AddressingProperties maps = ContextUtils.retrieveMAPs(message, false, true, false);
    if (maps != null) {
        LOGGER.debug("WS-Addressing is enabled");
        if (!ContextUtils.isRequestor(message)) {
            LOGGER.debug("Ignoring response message");
            return;
        }
        EndpointReferenceType replyTo = maps.getReplyTo();
        if (replyTo == null) {
            return;
        }
        AttributedURIType replyToAddress = replyTo.getAddress();
        if (replyToAddress.getValue().startsWith("http") && !replyToAddress.getValue().startsWith("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/")) {
            LOGGER.debug("Address is already absolute: {}", replyToAddress.getValue());
            return;
        }
        RequestAttributes currentRequestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        String contextPath = null;
        if (currentRequestAttributes != null) {
            LOGGER.debug("HttpServletRequest is accessible");
            contextPath = ((ServletRequestAttributes) currentRequestAttributes).getRequest().getContextPath();
        } else {
            LOGGER.debug("Can't access HttpServletRequest, replyTo address will use default context path");
            contextPath = "/a_server";
        }
        String url = "http://" + this.hostName + ":" + this.hostPort + contextPath + "/cxf/async_endpoint";
        LOGGER.debug("Setting replyTo URL to: {}", url);
        replyToAddress.setValue(url);
    } else {
        LOGGER.debug("WS-Addressing is disabled");
    }
}
}
```